# Tkinter GUI is not showing, But Response is received for the functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, websocket

Im trying to create GUI using tkinter, objective is to call a function from Button(Tkinter Window), without websocket function , i'm able to get Tkinter window and able to execute the function via button, trying the same with Websocket client function, functions are executed at first and Tkinter window is not showing UP.

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import *
import websocket
import threading
window=Tk()
window.title("Scalp")
window.geometry('400x400')
window.config(bg='lavender')


def Login():
    import requests
    import json
    global tokens

    headers = {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    url = 'https://api.stocknote.com/login'
    myobj = { 'userId': 'DDXX12', 'password': 'Durant', 'yob': '1999'}

    res = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(myobj), headers = headers)
    tokens = res.json().get("sessionToken")
    print (res.text);
    print(tokens)

def on_message(ws, msg):
        print ("Message Arrived:" + msg)
        return
def on_error(ws, error):
        print (error)
        return
def on_close(ws):
        print ("Connection Closed")
        return
def on_open(ws):
        print ("Sending json")
        data='{"request":{"streaming_type":"quote", "data":{"symbols":[{"symbol":"45402_NFO"}]}, "request_type":"subscribe", "response_format":"json"}}'
        ws.send(data)
        ws.send("\n")
        return
def connection():
        Login()
        headers = {'x-session-token': tokens }
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://stream.stocknote.com", on_open = on_open, on_message = on_message, on_error = on_error, on_close = on_close, header = headers)
        ws.run_forever()
        return
a=Button(window,text='Login',width=12,bg='azure',command=Login(),fg='black',font('bold',14),activebackground='dark sea green',activeforeground='khaki3')
a.place(x=100,y=50)
b=Button(window,text='BankNifty',width=12,bg='azure',command=connection(),fg='black',font('bold',14),activebackground='dark sea green',activeforeground='khaki3')
b.place(x=100,y=90)
window.mainloop
```

Tkinter window is not appearing , but functions are executed directly.

Comment: Is it a copy-paste error or are parentheses missing at the very last line ? It should be `window.mainloop()`, otherwise the line would do nothing much.

Comment: @Lenormju  even without parentheses its working. when trying the same with tkinter, GUI is not showing UP.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432. Also, why do you import threading twice, but don't use it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.

First, you aren't calling `mainloop`. You need to change `window.mainloop` to be `window.mainloop()`.

The second problem is that you are immediately calling `connection` and `Login` at startup because you are specifying them wrong.

When creating a button, you must pass a *callable*. In your case you're immediately calling the function and then passing the result to the `command` option. You need to change `command=Login()` to `command=Login`, and change `command=connection()` to `command=connection`.

Finally, when `connection` is called, it calls  `ws.run_forever()`. That is a blocking call - it doesn't return. Because it doesn't return, the tkinter event loop (what gets started with `mainloop()`) never has a chance to run. Because it doesn't run, it can't process even basic events like requests to display the window.